# Wifi is disabled by Hardware Switch - Compaq 610

Tags: wireless, drivers

After installing Ubuntu 14.04 the wireless switch in the laptop is not getting switched on. It was working fine with windows8 earlier.

Here are some additional info

```
rfkill list all

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes

 lspci -nn | grep -i network

10:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection [8086:4222] (rev 02)
```

`sudo rfkill unblock all` (or wifi) is not working, I tried many times using it.

Comment: Which brand chipset does your laptop have for wi-fi broadcom or something else?
You can check that using lspci command. Sometimes in the past I've had to install extra drivers for enabling wi-fi.

Comment: Have you tried the [wireless switch](https://copy.com/0C6gvpiPNDWo)?

Comment: This is the output of lpsci command.                                30:00.0 Ethernet controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8042 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller (rev 10)

Answer (score -1):

1. `sudo rmmod -f ath9k`
2. `sudo rfkill unblock all`
3. `sudo modprobe ath9k`

Then suspend and wake up your laptop. Your wifi should work.

That worked for me, but just until I shut down my laptop, then I need to do the same thing again when I turn it on.

I found the above commands in some other question.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Although your answer may solve the original poster's question, it would be helpful if you explained the commands, or better yet linked to the question you got the commands from.