# "Wi-Fi is disabled by hardware switch" Asus X551C(X551CA) Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking, asus

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my Asus laptop and all went well until i tried to use the wifi and it says "Wi-Fi is disabled by hardware switch" and thats not good. I looke around here and only thing that worked was this: [Wifi is disabled by Hardware Switch - Compaq 610](https://askubuntu.com/questions/492960/wifi-is-disabled-by-hardware-switch-compaq-610)
It worked but like he said it works until reboot then i have to enter it again. rfkill list all shows

`0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

EDIT: I have seen, and it has worked for the most part. I still cant turn on/off from keyboard but i no longer have to suspend for it to be functional. chili you are AWESOME and i thank you very much .
`

Comment: Do you have a dual boot system with Windows OS? Do you have physical shortcut key to tuning ON/OFF for your wifi on your keyboard?

Comment: Well, i think i technically have windows on the hdd but not i dual boot... And i have the fn+f2 to turn on/off  the wifi but it has done nothing.

Comment: Is It On virtualbox installed? Does that work on windows? turn on the wifi by fn+f2 in windows and run `rfkill list all` and check if you see any changes. And if @chili555's answer works for you, so you want that on suspend and wakeup mode too?

Comment: Its not on virtualbox, it worked on windows, and chili555's i found and he simply told me how to make a majority of it automated. But the commands require me to suspend the laptop to make them work, i am wondering if there is a way to get around that also.

Answer (score 1):

Let's get the sequence of commands to run automatically on boot. Please open a terminal and do:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit. Right above the line exit 0, add these three lines:

```
rmmod -f ath9k
rfkill unblock all
modprobe ath9k
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor. Reboot.

Is it working as expected?

If this is ineffective or only partially effective, let's try a different technique. Please edit /etc/rc.local as I outlined above and remove the lines you added. Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Now do:

```
sudo -i
echo "options asus-nb-wmi wapf=1" > /etc/modprobe.d/asus.conf
exit
```

Then the Fn+F2 (or some such) key combination to enable and disable wireless should be working properly.

There are other possible values for wapf, so if =1 is ineffective, we will try the others.

Comment: Well this works just as it should, besides i still have to suspend and wake the laptop get it to work. Is there a way to also not have to do this?

Comment: Please check: lsmod | grep asus. Is the module asus-nb-wmi loaded? I may have a much better solution.

Comment: it says the following:

Comment: asus_nb_wmi            16990  0 '&'
asus_wmi               24191  1 asus_nb_wmi

Comment: I have no idea what it means but im sure its what you are looking for...

Comment: Please see my edit above.